# HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, server

I did a Dynamic project and implemented delete crud and after coding, I'm getting this error in my console first insertion and read cruds were working properly. After implementing delete crud I have got this error and I'm stuck in this part

> deleteItem method

Implemented a delete method in the Item class

```
public String deleteItem(String itemID) {
        
        String output = "";
        
        try {
            
            Connection con = connect();
            
            if(con == null) {
                
                return "Error while connecting to the database for deleting.";
            }
            //create a prepared statement
            String query = "delete from items where itemID=?";
            
            PreparedStatement preparedStmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            
            // binding values
            preparedStmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(itemID));
            
            // execute the statement
            preparedStmt.execute();
            con.close();
            
            output = "Deleted successfully";
            
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
                output = "Error while deleting the item.";
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
            return output   ;
    }
```

> jsp code

Below is my jsp code calling the delete item method

```
<%
    //Delete item----------------------------------
    if (request.getParameter("itemID") != null)
    {
        Item Items = new Item();
        String stsMsg = Items.deleteItem(request.getParameter("itemID"));
        session.setAttribute("statusMsg", stsMsg);
        
        //deleteItem(request.getParameter("itemID")); 

    }
%>
```

error

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error


Type Exception Report

Message Unable to compile class for JSP: 

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [59] in the jsp file: [/itemps.jsp]
The method deleteItem(String) is undefined for the type Item
56:     if (request.getParameter("itemID") != null)
57:     {
58:         Item Items = new Item();
59:         String stsMsg = Items.deleteItem(request.getParameter("itemID"));
60:         session.setAttribute("statusMsg", stsMsg);
61:         
62:         //deleteItem(request.getParameter("itemID")); 


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:213)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:482)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:392)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:362)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:346)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:605)
```

my full item class is given below

```
package com;
import java.sql.*;

public class Item {


    public Connection connect() {
        
        Connection con = null;
        
        try {
            
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/item",
            "root", null);
            
            //For testing
            System.out.print("Successfully connected");
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return con;

        
    }
    
public String insertItem(String code ,String name ,String price ,String desc) {
        
        String output = "";
        
        try
        {
            Connection con = connect();
            
            if(con == null ) {
                return "Error While connecting to the database ";
            }
            String query = "insert into item (itemID,itemCode,itemName,itemPrice,itemDesc)"
                    + "values (?,?,?,?,?)";
            
            PreparedStatement preparedStmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            
            // binding values
            preparedStmt.setInt(1, 0);
            preparedStmt.setString(2, code);
            preparedStmt.setString(3, name);
            preparedStmt.setDouble(4, Double.parseDouble(price));
            preparedStmt.setString(5, desc);
            
            preparedStmt.execute();
            con.close();
            
            output = "Inserted successfully";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        output = "Error while inserting";
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        
        return output ;
        
    }

    public String readItems() {
        
        String output = "";
        
        try {
            Connection con = connect();
            
            if (con == null) {
                
                return "Error While conecting  to the  database  for reading ";
            }
            //preapre the html table to be displayed
            
            output = "<table boder= '1'><tr><th>Item Code</th>"
                    +"<th>Item Name</th><th>Item Price</th>"
                    + "<th>Item Description</th>"
                    + "<th>Update</th><th>Remove</th></tr>";
            
            String query = "select * from item";
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            
            // iterate through the rows in the result set
            
            while(rs.next()) {
                
                String itemID = Integer.toString(rs.getInt("itemID"));
                String itemCode = rs.getString("itemCode");
                String itemName = rs.getString("itemName");
                String itemPrice = Double.toString(rs.getDouble("itemPrice"));
                String itemDesc = rs.getString("itemDesc");
                
                // Add a row into the html table
                output += "<tr><td>" + itemCode + "</td>";
                output += "<td>" + itemName + "</td>";
                output += "<td>" + itemPrice + "</td>";
                output += "<td>" + itemDesc + "</td>";
                // buttons
                output += "<td><input name='btnUpdate' "
                + " type='button' value='Update'></td>"
                + "<td><form method='post' action='items.jsp'>"
                + "<input name='btnRemove' "
                + " type='submit' value='Remove'>"
                + "<input name='itemID' type='hidden' "
                + " value='" + itemID + "'>" + "</form></td></tr>";
            }
            con.close();
            // Complete the html table
            
            output += "</table>";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        output = "Error while reading the items.";
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return output;
    }
    
    public String deleteItem(String itemID) {
        
        String output = "";
        
        try {
            
            Connection con = connect();
            
            if(con == null) {
                
                return "Error while connecting to the database for deleting.";
            }
            //create a prepared statement
            String query = "delete from items where itemID=?";
            
            PreparedStatement preparedStmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            
            // binding values
            preparedStmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(itemID));
            
            // execute the statement
            preparedStmt.execute();
            con.close();
            
            output = "Deleted successfully";
            
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
                output = "Error while deleting the item.";
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
            return output   ;
    }
        
        
    
    
    
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: *Where* did you put that `deleteItem` method listed in the question? What you've listed lacks context. And do you have an `Items` class as well?

Comment: @nitind its items object not a class

Comment: i have put that method in the item class so that I called that in the jsp

Comment: We can't see that. Show us why the message is wrong.

Comment: @nitind I have mentioned that in the last part the error

Comment: You're not saying that there isn't an `Items` class, only that you mean that to refer to a local variable there. Show the package and project structure in the Package Explorer. Basically we're not seeing enough to find out what to fix because what you have written sure sounds like it should work, and yet it doesn't, and the compiler doesn't tend to get this part wrong.

Comment: @nitind what do you want the full java class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230082/discussion-between-track-suit-and-nitind).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it says `The method deleteItem(String) is undefined for the type Item`, can you try building project again

Comment: what do you mean by building again

Comment: i don't have enough reps to comment, so had to put it as ans, In eclipse select project , build project. if its maven project, you can try clean install

Comment: in my eclipse its a dynamic project and automatic build is ticked in that project

Comment: that build is there in automatically